Three fiber properly initializing InstancedMesh with useEffect to prevent unnecessary updates
I am creating a three-fiber project of a globe with different markers in cities. The idea is that you can click on a marker to see information about the city.
To create the markers, I am using an instancedMesh and a useEffect, where I assign the data that each instance will have.
My current challenge is to ensure that the useEffect only runs when the component is created, which involves passing an empty list to it. I'm finding that markers are only displayed when the useEffect listens for any changes, but this approach leads to visual bugs.
Below, I leave the code as reduced as I could.
const dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
const dummyColour = new THREE.Color();

export default function Marker() {
  const instancedMeshRef = useRef<THREE.InstancedMesh>();

  let markerID = 0;
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    Object.values(locations).forEach(({ countryName, cities }) => {
      cities.forEach(({ cityName, coordinates, color, level }) => {
        const { x, y, z } = getCartesianFromGeo(coordinates);

        dummy.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
        dummy.updateMatrix();
        instancedMeshRef.current?.setColorAt(markerID, dummyColour.set(color));
        instancedMeshRef.current?.setMatrixAt(markerID, dummy.matrix);
        markerID++;
      });
    });
    if (instancedMeshRef.current) {
      instancedMeshRef.current.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  }, []);

  let markerShader: WebGLProgramParametersWithUniforms;
  const markerGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.2, 0.2);

  const markerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  markerMaterial.onBeforeCompile = (shader: WebGLProgramParametersWithUniforms) => {
    shader.uniforms.time = { value: 0.0 };
    shader.vertexShader = `attribute float phase;
                     varying float vPhase;
                     ${shader.vertexShader}`.replace(
      `#include <begin_vertex>`,
      `#include <begin_vertex>
                     vPhase = phase; // de-synch of ripples`,
    );

    shader.fragmentShader = `
                     uniform float time;
                     varying float vPhase;
                     ${shader.fragmentShader}`.replace(
      `vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, opacity );`,
      markerExpansion,
    );
    markerShader = shader;
  };
  markerMaterial.defines = { USE_UV: " " }; // needed to be set to be able to work with UVs

  return (
    <instancedMesh
      ref={instancedMeshRef as React.Ref<THREE.InstancedMesh<THREE.BufferGeometry<THREE.NormalBufferAttributes>>>}
      args={[markerGeometry, markerMaterial, 1]}
    ></instancedMesh>
  );
}

I tried logging the instancedMeshRef in the console to see what was happening. I saw it is executed twice when the useEffect listens for all the changes. On the other hand, as expected, it is only executed once when it only listens for the construction of the component.
I tried to look for differences between the instancedMeshRef of the first log and the second, and there don't seem to be any. However, without that second run, the markers are never shown.
In the examples in the Three Fiber documentation, you can hear the component's construction, and I couldn't find the difference between the example code in the documentation and mine.
(https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/advanced/scaling-performance).
Some information that I think may be useful:
I am using the following versions:
three: 0.151.3
fiber: 8.15.16
drei: 9.99.3
Also I think this question could be similar as mine, but does not have any response: How to Use Sprites in InstancedMesh with Three.js and React Three Fiber in React?
I appreciate your assistance in this matter. Thank you in advance for your help!
